Is it possible for state["response"] not raise KeyError: 'response' when the property is not there
I'm looking at this example here under the Create the Graph section:
class PlanExecute(TypedDict):
    input: str
    plan: List[str]
    past_steps: Annotated[List[Tuple], operator.add]
    response: str


def should_end(state: PlanExecute):
    if state["response"]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

For me it throws the KeyError: 'response' exception.
Naturally I'd do it like this:
def should_end(state: PlanExecute):
    return 'response' in state

or like this
def should_end(state: PlanExecute):
    if state.get("response"):
        return True
    else:
        return False

But I'm wondering why in the example that's supposed to work they used the construction that throws the error. Is it simply a typo or there are some cases under which the error wouldn't be thrown?

It's bound to be a typo (or since it's an .ipynb file, the code someone actually executed 2 months ago is not what was recorded in the notebook).
Since the TypedDict is not total=False or use NotRequired, all dicts conforming to that type should be
{"input": "foo", "plan": [], "past_steps": [], "response": ""}

but of course that type is not enforced at runtime...

thanks! could you please elaborate a bit more on Since the TypedDict is not total=False or use NotRequired ?

Not sure I can do better than the docs for TypedDict: marking the whole thing total=False means that any defined key can be omitted; NotRequired on a field marks that key as omittable.
